# Put pork in crock pot and accidentally set to warm

Tags: food-safety, pork, pot, crockpot

I put a large pork roast in the crock pot this morning and accidentally set it to warm. I noticed it about 2 hours later and turned it to high. Is it safe to eat or do I need to toss it and buy a new one?

Comment: Please see the [food safety wiki](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info), which answers this question as well as all other "food left out" questions pretty definitively. 2 hours is at the very edge of the USDA guidelines, which makes this a pretty low risk but not quite risk-free. It also depends on what your crock pot's "warm" temperature actually is; if it's at or above 140° F then there's less of a risk. That's about all we can tell you.

Comment: (Note: As per previous discussions, I'm closing this as Too Localized rather than trying to find an "exact" duplicate. The circumstances are slightly different, the answer is - as always - the same, and in the tag wiki.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of related questions regarding crockpots and food safety on this site but I found this informative link that will help explain why you may not want to risk keeping that roast that has been in a safety danger zone (below 165 F) for more than an hour.  The meat becomes a bacteria breeding ground, in essence.

http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/safetysanitation/p/slowcooksafe.htm